# How can I delete a photo on multiple devices without having to delete it manually everywhere?

Tags: photos.app

I'm using `Photos` for iOS and MacOS to store my photos. When deleting a photo from either device, nothing happens with the photos on the other, not even after syncing. How can I avoid having to manually delete a photo on both devices for it to disappear? I'm not using iCloud sync.

Answer (score 1):

Without iCloud, the images are just imported, not synced. There's no tangible connection between the two. This the same behavior has you'd find with a camera's memory card.

Before iCloud, images were synced via iTunes. You can still sync images back to the iOS device via iTunes, but if you do that the iOS device can't delete them.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this sentence: "You can still sync images back to the iOS device via iTunes, but if you do that the iOS device can't delete them." Do you mean that I can't delete photos from my iOS device that at one point in time have been synced from macOS?

Comment: This means that if you remove items from your iOS device and then instruct iTunes so sync photos to the device, you must use iTunes to remove them.